# express-validator error message attributes and location

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am using expressJS, Node and Handlebars.

In my post function I have the following:

**routes.js**

```
req.assert("referenceNumber", "Enter ...").notEmpty();
req.assert("yourPostcode", "Enter ...").notEmpty();

var errors = req.validationErrors(true);

if (errors) {
   res.render('<page>/index', {
   title: "<title>",
   errors: errors
});

} else {
   // Redirection
}
```

**index.hbs**

```
{{#if errors}}
 <ul>
  {{#each errors}}
    <li><a href="#">{{this.msg}}</a></li>
  {{/each}}
 </ul>
{{/if}}
```

This outputs a list of errors on submission which is great. The problem is I need the error message located next to the form field as well as.

So ideally I can target each error by name e.g. "referenceNumber", "yourPostcode".

I have thought about maybe having a variable inside the **routes.js** like so:

```
if (errors) {
   res.render('<page>/index', {
   title: "<title>",
   referenceNumber: <something>,
   yourPostcode: <something>
});
```

And perhaps be able to do something funky this way.

It would also be very good associating an id with each error message to act as an anchor link to each error form field.

Totally stumped with this one, and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Can anyone shed some light on this please? Suggestions?